# asp.net-mvc ajax query on keypress rather than submit button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, keypress

I am using Ajax.BeginForm to update data on a webpage (as per the code below).  Is there anyway i can hit the backend server on every keypress instead of waiting for hitting the submit button

this way, when i type "a", it will query on "a' and show all the db results then if i type "b"  it will filter the list on "ab" and so forth  . . .

**Current Code using Submit Button**

```
 <%using (Ajax.BeginForm("GetPeople", "Contacts", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "Contacts", LoadingElementId = "updating", OnSuccess = "done" }))
  { %>

<fieldset style="text-align:left">
<legend>Contacts Search</legend>
<table>
<tr><td>First Name:</td><td> <input style="width:300px" type="text" name="FirstPattern" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Last Name: </td><td><input style="width:300px" type="text" name="LastPattern" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggesting looking at the jQuery [Autocomplete](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/) plugin.  It does exactly what you are asking for and only requires that you have a action that responds to the queries that it creates and returns the matching set based on the query parameters.  It's highly configurable and well-tested.  In your case, you'd need to take advantage of the ability to add parameters to get it to use multiple search criteria like first and last name.  For example, use last name as the main autocomplete and send any characters in the first name field as additional values for the query.

Comment: if i use autocomplete, don't i have to select one item ultimately, i want to allow people to enter partial values so i can do "like" queries on the server.  would jquery autocomplete stop me from allowing partial entries ?

Comment: No, you can continue to enter text in the field and it need not match one of the selected options.  This is controlled by the mustMatch option, which is false by default.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following on a text box and I check for a keypress and then go out to the backend to get a list of suburbs.

```
    $("#suburb").keyup(function(evt) {
        var suburb = jQuery.trim($("#suburb").val());

        if (suburb.length < 3)
            return;

        $("#suburbList").empty();
        $("#suburbList").attr("style", "position:absolute; top:230px; width:150px; left:100px; padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; background-color:#f0f0f0; border:1px solid black;");

        $.post("/Home/GetSuburbList", { suburb: suburb },
            function(suburbs) {
                $.each(suburbs, function(i, thisSuburb) {

                    $("#suburbList").append($('<a/>')
                                .attr("href", "#")
                                .click(function(evt) { $("#suburb").val(thisSuburb.name); $("#suburbList").empty(); $("#suburbList").attr("style", "position:absolute; top:230px; width:150px; left:100px; padding:5px 5px 5px 5px; background-color:#f0f0f0; border:1px solid black; display:none;"); })
                                .html(thisSuburb.name + "<br/>"));

                });
            }, "json");

    });
```